# Install postgres 9.6 on a windows 11 machine fails because C++ runtime bundled is superceded

Tags: postgresql, windows, installation

I have been forced to move to a windows 11 machine for development/support and need to be able to run postgres 9.6x for user maintenance. Newer users are on 13.x, but many are still on postgres 9.x
It would not matter but the schema comparison tool we use does not scan well from postgres 13 databases back to 9.6 or vice versa, when comparing a user database to the current build to make an upgrade delta.

Is it possible with command line options to run the installer without running the C++ installer, or to ignore errors when it fails?

I can try building the latest release on the win 11 machine, but if there is a better solution I'll take advice.

Comment: Most people these days would be thinking virtual machine or container or similar when you need to support older variants on a newer machine.